# Implementing Stripe with NextJS and Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, next.js, stripe-payments

I would like to accept payments on my NextJS + Rails (backend) application. The Rails backend handles bookings and has a few tables (user, bookings, etc). I want it to be as 'easy' as possible so Stripe Checkout seems to be a good fit.

However, I struggle to understand if I need to set up Stripe only using NextJS (front + NextJS API), or if I should do the backend part using the Rails server.

The Stripe docs only show the Stripe set up with NextJS (front) and NextJS api.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hello  While the term “easy” is subjective,  I think Stripe Checkout with Prebuilt Checkout page flow would be an ideal choice. It has a pretty solid guide to get started [1] as well as it requires a lot less code and offers various customization options.

All you have to do is;

- Build a form on your NextJS frontend that makes a POST request on your backend
- Build a route on your rails app that creates a Stripe Checkout session [2]
- Then redirect the users to the Stripe hosted
  checkout page

Stripe will take care of accepting the payments and sending users back to your app [3].

While there are no official example docs on Stripe Integration with Rails, you can tweak the Ruby + Sinatra snippets to fit into your rails app.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby#create_checkout_session-success_url

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=ruby#create_checkout_session-cancel_url

[5] https://stripe.com/partners/pay-rails